# Android TextView doesn't "wrap_content" when setting text

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, textview

I have an Activity where I have a `ViewPager2` and a `TextView` below it. When scrolling through the `ViewPager2`, I use `registerOnPageChangeCallback` to set the text for the `TextView` accordingly.

When I first start the activity, `registerOnPageChangeCallback` is triggered, where the text from the first Element is set to the `TextView` correctly. However, the height is not adjusted accordingly, even though the layout sets it to `wrap_content`. The `TextView` stays in a status where it basically has the height of one line, so any text long enough to occupy a new line is cut short, because the `TextView` is not large enough to show it.

Same goes for its underlying `ConstraintLayout`, which I have discovered using different background colors.

Once I start to swipe the `ViewPager2`, `registerOnPageChangeCallback`is called again, the text is changed accordingly and this time the `TestView`'s height is correctly adjusted.

I have tried calling `forceLayout()` after setting the text or set `android:scrollHorizontally="false"` for the `TextView` but it changes nothing.

When I set `android:lines="3"`, then that enlarges the initial size of the TextView to the height of three lines but obviously that doesn't adjust either. Setting e.g. `android:maxLines="6"` does nothing.

**layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/backgroundColor">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00A">

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/viewPager2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="4:3"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descriptionTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/viewPager2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            tools:text="text that is way too long to fit into one line and thereby has to have two lines"
            android:background="#0A0"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**onPageChangeCallback**

```
viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(
            object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
                override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                    super.onPageSelected(position)
                    // getting my data

                    descriptionTextView.text = data.description
                }
            }
        )
```

Another odd thing is, when I remove `android:textSize="18sp"`, the text view doesn't resize at all. So the following behavior occurred:

1. Removed `android:textSize="18sp"` -> TextView doesnt resize at all
2. Keeping `android:textSize="18sp"` -> TextView resizes only after first swipe in `ViewPager2`

This behavior is odd to me and I don't understand how this could occur or how I could fix it. Why does this behavior occur, and what I can do to consistently have the `TextView` resize itself correctly from the start?

### Edit

I have tried removing the ScrollView and letting the ConstraintLayout be the root element. Same things happens. Meaning that it's the TextView that doesn't resize, even if its parent has enough space.

Answer (score -1):

The ViewPager2 does not support the wrap_content which results in showing a same height for all pages as that of the first page in the pager. You need to write a custom ViewPager which will override the onMeasure and need to add additional logic to calculate the height of the page and set that.

Reference link: https://medium.com/winkl-insights/how-to-have-a-height-wrapping-viewpager-when-images-have-variable-heights-on-android-60b18e55e72e

Comment: You misunderstood the question.
I dont want the height of the viewpager to be adjusted, I want the height of a TextView outside the viewpager to be adjusted